# How to make grand parent and parent checked when child check box is selected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make the checkboxes work in such a way that when 'Edit Property' is selected Property, abc, def and ghi also gets selected. And when any of the child abc, def or ghi gets selected, Edit Property and Property must also get selected. Edit Property and Property must get unselected when all child checkbox abc, def and ghi gets unselected.
Can anyone suggest without altering the HTML code and using jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "li:has(li) > input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
  $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox'] ~ ul input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).closest("li:has(li)").children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).closest('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked'));
  });
})
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="Property" />Property
    <ul>
      <li id="Edit_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit_Property" />Edit_Property
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">abc</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">def</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">ghi</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Remove_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove_Property" />Remove_Property
      </li>
      <li id="Add_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add_Property" />Add_Property
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name='Testimonial' />Testimonial
    <ul>
      <li id="Add">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add" />Add
      </li>
      <li id="Remove">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove" />Remove
      </li>
      <li id="View">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="View" />View
      </li>
      <li id="Edit">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit" />Edit
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the parent() method https://api.jquery.com/parent/ ?

Comment: You need to traverse all the parents of abc, def, ghi. Try using parents() method of jquery it will traverse all its parents.https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method in combination with **[prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** to check the checkbox that you need. Try this:

```js
 $(function() {
   $(document).on("change", "li:has(li) > input[type='checkbox']", function() {
     $(this).parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
     $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
   $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox'] ~ ul input[type='checkbox']", function() {
     var l_1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.child').nextAll().find('input:checked').length;
     var l_2 = $(this).parent().parent().find('input:checked').length;
     var c = $(this).closest('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked');
     if (l_1 == 0 && c == false) {
       $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
       $(this).closest("li:has(li)").children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', c);
     } else if (l_1 > 0 && c == true || l_2 > 0 && c == true) {
       $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
       $(this).closest("li:has(li)").children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', c);
     }
   });
 })
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="Property" />Property
    <ul>
      <li id="Edit_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit_Property" />Edit_Property
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">abc</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">def</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">ghi</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Remove_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove_Property" />Remove_Property
      </li>
      <li id="Add_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add_Property" />Add_Property
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name='Testimonial' />Testimonial
    <ul>
      <li id="Add">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add" />Add
      </li>
      <li id="Remove">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove" />Remove
      </li>
      <li id="View">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="View" />View
      </li>
      <li id="Edit">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit" />Edit
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank u very much for the code. But still got an issue, if I check abc,def and ghi and I unselect one of the three, Property and Edit Property also gets unselected. Property and Edit Property must get unselected only when all child checkbox i.e abc,def and ghi gets unselected. Please Help

Comment: @Birju, you can check the number of selected elements. There is no easy solution. But you can get the number of checked checkboxes something like `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.child').nextAll().find('input:checked').length;` and deselect the inputs based on that, when it's `0`. I hope this helps you.

Comment: can u please edit and send. Please its very much urgent. I am almost new to AJAX and JQuery. Please